# ESP USB interfacing without using serial terminals or consoles (tinyusb)

Tags: c, eclipse, esp32, esp-idf

I've been recently working on a project that requires I interface an ESP32-S3 with a separate main computer through USB, the basic gist is that I want the central device to be able to receive simple 2-byte packets from the ESP, and vice versa.

I've been looking at some example code from esp (particularly, the serial device example, which I know contradicts my intentions), as well as reading the API Reference for the USB Device Drivers, the USB OTG Console, and the USB Serial/JTAG controller console, and from all of this I've been trying to figure out how to just send a 16-bit void* output from the USB and then (also from the USB) receive a similar input and look at it.

From reading the documentation and the example, i assumed that the USB is driven by the `tinyusb_cdcacm_register_callback` function, which, when I looked into it, wasn't very well documented, there's a function inside that function called `get_acm` which returns the subclass object inside of a given `esp_tusb_cdcacm_t`, then this function has another function inside it that I decided not to read because I was getting nowhere, it seems reverse-engineering this code isn't my best bet, so I've come here for some help regarding maybe figuring out where I can find some example of functions similar to

```
bool send(uint16_t packet){
   // assumes USB has been set up earlier
   // Literally just take the packet and transmit it over
   // return success or fail
}

uint16_t receive(/*device*/){
   // Once again assumed the USB has been setup already
   // Checks to see what's coming in from the USB
   // Returns the value if success, 0 if fail
}
```

it's also important to note that I've been looking through the ESP documentation, not the tinyusb documentation, which I understand tinyusb is its own library with its own documentation. This is simply because I've been seeing the ESP code, which seems to use a slightly modified version of tusb made especially for ESP32s.

Another important detail is that I plan on reading the sent signals with my own code, as well. So the other code should also do the same thing, just look at whatever's coming in from the USB port and send something in return (except the main device will have up to 4 ESP32s connected to it through USB).

is that even possible to do or recommended at all? Is there a better way to do this? I'm not looking to be handed the code, just maybe get pointed in the right direction as to where I can find examples of something similar or if I should just switch from USB to something like using the GPIO or the UART ports, which I am much more familiar with from previous projects. Is there maybe a way to individually drive D+ and D-? (I think I understand how they're supposed to work... but by saying that I'm basically saying I barely would know anything about it)

Answer (score 1):

> particularly, the serial device example, which I know contradicts my
> intentions

What is stopping you from sending and receiving 2-byte messages using USB CDC? Nothing. I think you do not understand serial communication and confuse it with "console"

You can also use the USB HID class.

I would not recommend using any custom classes as you need to write your own driver on the host machine and it requires advanced USB and host OS knowledge (which I think is far beyond your level [judging it from the question asked] at the moment). CDC and HID class devices are supported "out of the box" by all modern operating systems.

I would recommend to learn some USB basics - [some basics in this link](https://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/)

You can answer the rest of your questions yourself when you read and understand what USB is and how it works.,

Comment: "I think you do not understand serial communication".

That's a very good diagnosis of the problem. I'm still slightly confused about it, but I'll read the link. Thanks.